# Proxy Pass Subdirectory in Apache Passenger with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, reverse-proxy

I have a rails app (`www.myapp.com`) for which I am using Apache Passenger. The virtual host is configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp/current/public"
  RailsEnv production
  <directory "/var/www/myapp/current/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </directory>
  RailsBaseURI /
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a blog which is hosted externally on some other domain, lets say `www.myapp-blog.com`. I want to 301 redirect any requests to `www.myapp.com/blog` or `www.myapp.com/blog/*` to the relevant pages on `www.myapp-blog.com`. Everything else should flow through my Rails app.

How should I modify the above virtual host configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use apache port forwarding technique...

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyRequests Off
      ServerName www.myapp-blog.com
      ServerAlias myapp-blog.com
      ProxyPass / http://www.myapp.com/blog/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://www.myapp.com/blog
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How does this maintain the second requirement where everything else must flow through my Rails app?

Comment: if you want to redirect from one url to another in same app. then you need to specify your  second url in proxyPass and proxyReversePass. you can use port number if they are running on same server. i think you will not need 301 redirect. read more about apache  redirection .